# Building NaCl SDK from source for ARM-32

Tags: google-nativeclient

I am trying to build Native Client SDK from source code following instructions on: www.chromium.org/nativeclient/how-tos/building-and-testing-gcc-and-gnu-binutils.   After I run *make clean build-with-newlib -j16,* I get errors. When I saw the contents of Makefile, I realized that CROSS_ARCH was set to x86_64. Changing it to arm32 threw different kind of errors.  What are the settings to generate binaries for ARM platform?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building toolchain for Native Client on ARM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677584/building-toolchain-for-native-client-on-arm)